# Typo3 store sql table definitions in separate files

Tags: extjs, typo3

Got to make my first steps with typo3, now.

Got an Extension, some tables in `...typo3conf\ext\my_extension\ext_tables.sql` and would like to put each table Definition in a separate file, because it gets very long.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The best would still be to put everything into the `ext_tables.sql` file as many checks are happening with this file like if you add new fields, remove fields, add tables, the DB compare in the Install Tool can handle that.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at an example in CMS7

```
/typo3/sysext/install/Classes/Controller/Action/Tool/UpgradeWizard.php::silentCacheFrameworkTableSchemaMigration()
```

Where given SQL file is used to perform update. fx:

```
/typo3/sysext/core/Resources/Private/Sql/Cache/Backend/Typo3DatabaseBackendCache.sql
```